# php autoloading: what namespace does the class come from?

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload

Im inside a `spl_autoload_register()` registered function. Here I can get the classname, but how to determine which namespace it is?

Comment: It does not happen automatically or by a PHP function you must structure you application in such a way that the `spl_autoload_register` can identify that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the current namespace:

```
namespace MyProject;

echo '"', __NAMESPACE__, '"'; // outputs "MyProject"
```

else you store in a config file or by(stated in the comment by application structure) I suppose...

Answer (score 2):

Try this example. You can define a class that handle your calls

```
<?php
namespace Example;

#Define a classLoader object
class Loader{
/**
 * Construct and set the autoloader class handler
 */
public function __construct() {
    spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'loadClass'));
}

/**
 * This method is called when an object is loaded
 * 
 * @param string $args
 */
public function loadClass($args){
    var_dump($args);
    //REMOVE: this is only for killing the process
    die;
}
}

//Create your autoloader object
new Loader();

//Calling some class
new \Some\Name\Space\Example();
```

You should get some response like this.

```
string(23) "Some\Name\Space\Example"
```